# Can't Update Multi record Error Transaction is Inactive

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am trying to update multi records with Transaction ebean, however when I am trying more than one record, there is an error on the screen :

**[IllegalStateException: Transaction is Inactive]**

**any idea please ?**

```
public Result savemulti(String selected) throws PersistenceException {
    Form<Computer> computerForm = formFactory.form(Computer.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(computerForm.hasErrors()) {return badRequest(views.html.computers.editMulti.render(AuthorisedUser.findByEmail(request().username()), computerForm, selected));}
    java.util.Date dtcreate = new java.util.Date();
    String connectedEmail = ctx().session().get("email");
    AuthorisedUser singleUser = AuthorisedUser.findByEmail(connectedEmail);
    String[] ids = selected.split(";");
    Transaction txn = Ebean.beginTransaction();
    try{
        for (String temp : ids){  
            Computer savedComputer = Computer.find.byId(Long.parseLong(temp));
            if (savedComputer != null){
                Computer newComputerData = computerForm.get();
                savedComputer.company = newComputerData.company;
                savedComputer.discontinued = newComputerData.discontinued;
                savedComputer.introduced = newComputerData.introduced;
                savedComputer.name = newComputerData.name;
                savedComputer.status = newComputerData.status;          
                savedComputer.moddt = new java.sql.Timestamp(dtcreate.getTime());            
                savedComputer.modby = singleUser.userName;
                savedComputer.site = singleUser.site;                

                savedComputer.update();
                flash("success", "Computer [ " + computerForm.get().name + " ] has been updated");
                txn.commit();
            }
        }            
    } finally {
        txn.end();
    }        
    return GO_HOME;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put for before transaction and it works perfectly, thank you.

```
 public Result savemulti(String selected) throws PersistenceException {

  Form<Computer> computerForm = formFactory.form(Computer.class).bindFromRequest();
  if(computerForm.hasErrors()) {return badRequest(views.html.computers.editMulti.render(AuthorisedUser.findByEmail(request().username()), computerForm, selected));}

    java.util.Date dtcreate = new java.util.Date();
    String connectedEmail = ctx().session().get("email");
    AuthorisedUser singleUser = AuthorisedUser.findByEmail(connectedEmail); 


  String[] ids = selected.split(";");

          for (String temp : ids) 
          {  
      Transaction txn = Ebean.beginTransaction();


        try 
        {


            Computer savedComputer = Computer.find.byId(Long.parseLong(temp));
            if (savedComputer != null) 
            {
                Computer newComputerData = computerForm.get();
                savedComputer.company = newComputerData.company;
                savedComputer.active = newComputerData.active;
                savedComputer.discontinued = newComputerData.discontinued;
                savedComputer.introduced = newComputerData.introduced;
                savedComputer.name = newComputerData.name;
                savedComputer.status = newComputerData.status;           
                savedComputer.moddt = new java.sql.Timestamp(dtcreate.getTime());            
                savedComputer.modby = singleUser.userName;
                savedComputer.site = singleUser.site;                

                savedComputer.update();

                txn.commit();
            }
          }            

          finally { txn.end(); }         
}

  flash("success", "Computers [ " + selected + " ] has been updated");

  return GO_HOME;
}
```